# Choosing initial velocity in pyswarm (Particle Swarm Optimization)

Tags: particle-swarm

I have been trying to set an initial velocity in pyswarms according to the function pyswarms.backend.generators.generate_velocity(n_particles, dimensions, clamp=None):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fymxb.png)

https://pyswarms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/pyswarms.backend.html#module-pyswarms.backend.generators

However it seems that the pyswarms.single.global_best module does not allow for an initial velocity, only for an initial position of the swarm.

class pyswarms.single.global_best.GlobalBestPSO(n_particles, dimensions, options, bounds=None, oh_strategy=None, bh_strategy='periodic', velocity_clamp=None, vh_strategy='unmodified', center=1.0, ftol=-inf, ftol_iter=1, init_pos=None)

https://pyswarms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/pyswarms.single.html#module-pyswarms.single.global_best

Any idea how to implement an initial velocity (rather than a velocity clamp)?
The reason I need this is because I have a highly multimodal system where I would like some particles within my swarm to start at an earlier found local minimum with relatively low velocity, without limiting the rest of my swarm to a low velocity. In any case I am curious how to use the pyswarms.backend.generators.generate_velocity(n_particles, dimensions, clamp=None) if not within the pyswarms.single.global_best module. Thanks!